# How can I redraw the ribbon UI Elements

Tags: mfc, windows-ribbon-framework

I am doing a MFC Ribbon programming based on MDI environments.

I want to change the elements of the MFC Ribbon gallery button on runtime.

So I create a `HBITMAP` objects on runtime and using `SetPallete` method in `CMFCToolBarImage` class.

My code is below.

```
CMFCRibbonGallery* pGallery = (CMFCRibbonGallery*)pRibbon->FindByID(ID_BUTTON_LABEL_CONTROL_GALLERY);
CMFCToolBarImages test;
test.SetImageSize(t);
test.AddImage(hBitmap, 0);
pGallery->Clear();
pGallery->SetPalette(test);
pGallery->RedrawIcons();
```

When i run this code, the ribbon gallery button is deleted, but there is no elements in the gallery button.

Strange thing is when I Minimize/Maximize the window, The Icons are visible at the button.

How can Icons are visible without minimize/maximize the window?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and call `CMFCRibbonBar::RecalcLayout`, this function forces the complete ribbon layout to be recalculated and redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

`RecalcLayout()` is sometimes not enough. In that case use `ForceRecalcLayout()`, that will do the trick.